# React Redux state not changing after calling useDispatch() [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**SOLVED**

I'm trying to use the newer version of react redux `v8.0.2` within my web-based game to keep state within my application without having to pass states between navigation calls.

Unfortunately I'm running into an issue where the player state gets initialized for the first time, but the final state is not being updated after calling the `useDispatch()` method.  I've tried looking everywhere online, but none of the solutions that are currently out there have actually solved my issue.

I even force my functional component to rerender, and that still just returns the initial state of my player instead of the updated one that I'm expecting.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing here.  It's got to be something small that isn't talked about on the redux forms/docs.  TIA!

playerSlice.js

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const playerSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'player',
    initialState: {
        address: '',
        cp: 0,
        created: '',
        faction: 0,
        faction_selected: false,
        games_lost: 0,
        games_won: 0,
        online: false,
        selected_char: 0,
        selected: {
            combatType: '',
            lvl: 0,
            mgc: 0,
            str: 0,
            rng: 0,
            def: 0
        },
        time_played: 0,
        tokens: 10000,
        total_cp: 0,
        total_earned: 0,
        user_name: ""
    },
    reducers: {
        setInit: (state,action) => {
            state = action.payload;
        },
        setCP: (state,action) => {
            state.cp += action.payload;
        },
        setFaction: (state,action) => {
            state.faction = action.payload;
        },
        setGamesLost: (state,action) => {
            state.games_lost = action.payload;
        },
        setGamesWon: (state,action) => {
            state.games_won = action.payload;
        },
        setPlayerState: (state,action) => {
            state = {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        }
    }
});

export const {setInit, setCP, setFaction, setGamesLost, setGamesWon, setPlayerState} = playerSlice.actions;

export const selectPlayer = (state) => state.player;

export default playerSlice.reducer;
```

index.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import playerReducer from '../store/playerSlice';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        player: playerReducer,
    },
})
```

Selection.js

```
import Card from './Card';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../stylesheet/Selection.css';
import Logo from '../assets/degen age title GNW skull.png';
import KnightTitle from '../assets/knights title.png';
import GoblinTitle from '../assets/goblins title.png';
import WizardTitle from '../assets/wizards title.png';
import ElfTitle from '../assets/elves title.png';
import SorcererShield from '../assets/sorcerers shield item.jpg';
import Weaken from '../assets/weaken item img.jpg';
import Barrage from '../assets/barrage item img.jpg';
import Berserk from '../assets/berserk item img.jpg';
import {db} from '../firebase/firestore';
import {addDoc,collection, serverTimestamp} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {CHAR_RACES} from '../constants';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {setInit, selectPlayer} from '../store/playerSlice';

const SCREEN_DELAY = 4000; // delay in ms

const Selection = () => {
    const [initScreen, setInitScreen] = useState(true);
    const player = useSelector(selectPlayer);  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [ready,setReady] = useState(false);
    const {state} = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;

        if(mounted){
            setTimeout(() => {
                setInitScreen(false);
            },SCREEN_DELAY);
        }

        return () => {
            mounted = false;
        }
    },[]);

    const handleFactionSelect = async (_faction) => {
        // add new player to db
        const ref = collection(db, 'players');
        const playerData = {
            address: state.address,
            cp: 0,
            created: serverTimestamp(),
            faction: _faction,
            faction_selected: true,
            games_lost: 0,
            games_won: 0,
            online: true,
            selected_char: 0,
            selected: {
                combatType: 'MELEE',
                lvl: 200,
                mgc: 10,
                str: 59,
                rng: 30,
                def: 101
            },
            time_played: 0,
            tokens: 10000,
            total_cp: 0,
            total_earned: 0,
            user_name: "someUser393900"
        }

        dispatch(setInit({
            ...playerData,
            created: new Date().getTime(),
            faction: _faction
        }))

        console.log({player});
        // set in redux as well****
        // addDoc(ref,playerData).then(res => {
        //     if(res.id){
        //         const _faction = CHAR_RACES[playerData.faction];
        //         dispatch(setInit({
        //             ...playerData,
        //             created: new Date().getTime(),
        //             faction: _faction
        //         }))
        //         // navigate('/play',{
        //         //     state: {
        //         //         player: {
        //         //             ...playerData,
        //         //             faction: _faction
        //         //         }
        //         //     }
        //         // });
        //         navigate('/play');
        //     }
        // }).catch(error => {
        //     console.error(error);
        // })
    }

    return (
        <div className='select-main'>
            {!initScreen ? <div id="main-select" className='fade-in-slow2 select-wrapper'>
                <h1 className='text-center'>CHOOSE YOUR SIDE</h1>
                <div className='select-cards'>
                    <Card cardStyle="f1" ability={SorcererShield} desc="Sorcerers Shield" title={WizardTitle} name={1} onClick={handleFactionSelect} />
                    <Card cardStyle="f3" ability={Berserk} desc="Berserk" title={KnightTitle} name={2} onClick={handleFactionSelect} />
                    <Card cardStyle="f2" ability={Barrage} desc="Barrage" title={ElfTitle} name={0} onClick={handleFactionSelect} />
                    <Card cardStyle="f4" ability={Weaken} desc="Weaken" title={GoblinTitle} name={3} onClick={handleFactionSelect} />
                </div>
            </div> :
            <div className='fade-in-slow sub-select-wrapper flex-just-center'>
                <div className='cracked'></div>
            </div>            
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Selection;
```

As you can see I'm attempting to call the `setInit` reducer from my redux store and then logging the new state after that.  I also know that trying to log the state directly after doesn't always reflect the most recent data, but I've tried by adding a state change to my component and log the player state afterwards and I just get the same data back again.  Nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    setInit: (state,action) => {
        state = action.payload;
    },
```

This doesn't do anything, it simply replaces the local variable `state` but Redux cannot possibly see that. You should either *mutate* the state, or return a new state. In your case, returning `action.payload` should work.

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately changing it to ```return action.payload``` did nothing.  The state remains the same.

Comment: Did you check the Redux devtools? Is your action being dispatched at all? Also your handleFactionSelect function is a bit weird. Why is it async? Where is the _faction argument coming from (right now it looks like _faction will be the event)

Comment: Your first useEffect is weird as well. The `mounted` variable will always be true when it reaches the `if`, so you probably meant to write something else, and it's unclear to me what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: Also if you do `console.log({player})` it will log the previous version of the state. Dispatching cannot possibly change the current value of the `player` variable synchronously, instead it asks React to rerender the component and this new rerender will have access to the new state.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I actually was able to find out why this wasn't working.  I actually had an error within my ```dispatch``` call which wasn't logging an actual error to the console because it must only be catching it within Redux devtools.  Fixed this, and the state changes and is retrievable as expected.